# Set default Head for all pages in NextJS?

Tags: next.js

Can you set a default value for the `Head` component in NextJS that other pages will extend from?

In my case I need to load a font on every page:

```
  <Head>
    <link
      href="path-to-font"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </Head>
```

I could do this with a custom document file, but a default value for `Head` seems simpler.

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `Head` doesn't require change often, you can take the custom document approach. However if you want things to be dynamic like different title for different pages I would suggest keeping the static layout in custome-document and the dynamic layout separate in another component like

in _document.js

```
// this will define the default layout for the page

render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <meta httpEquiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
          />
          // links for static assets
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
```

If you want things to be dynamic like the title, create a new Layout component that wraps all the components is a specific page.

```
const Layout = ({children, title="default title", description="default-description"}) => {


  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="description" content={description} />
        <title>{title}</title>
      </Head>
      // you can header component here
      <main>
        {children}
      </main>
      // you can add your footer component here
    </>
  );

}
```

Now you just need to wrap you page with the Layout for things to be dynamic.

```
const MyPage = (props) => {

  return (
    <Layout title="the-dynamic-title" description="the-dynamic-description">
      // all other components for your page goes here
    </Layout>
  )

}
```